# Can we install node using command line in windows/Mac ? is it possible ?

Tags: node.js, windows, macos

without using node installer, Can we install node in windows and Mac OS?

Comment: You can always just download and run the file trough command line

Comment: Or you can also use some kind of package manager, like: https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: Have you done any research such as googling: [How to install nodejs on windows via command prompt](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+install+nodejs+from+command+line&oq=windows+install+nodejs+&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.5049j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Install nodejs osx terminal](https://www.google.com/search?q=osx+install+nodejs+terminal&oq=osx+install+nodejs+terminal&aqs=chrome..69i57.5899j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @Sterling.. yes, I did google it before posting this question but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @ Yago..  I was hoping to achieve something one line install of node. Ex. How we install some node package(angular,babel - npm install angular). In the same kind, if I can install node.

Comment: @mdatsev.. that's the thing, I am looking another way to install node in my machine.

Comment: For windows you can use msiexec from command line:
msiexec.exe /a https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/node-v9.4.0-x64.msi /quiet

Comment: @denis.. sorry but nothing is happening with this : msiexec.exe /a nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/node-v9.4.0-x64.msi /quiet.

Comment: It's because of last argument "/quiet" , just remove it to see the process of installation

Answer (score 1):

If you want  install a Package from command line, you need a package manager like Yarn or Chocolatey for example :

**Using Chocolatey:**

```
cinst nodejs
# or for full install with npm
cinst nodejs.install
```

However i don't understand why you  want install a package manager with another package manager.. Just download Node from their website https://nodejs.org

Comment: Actually, I want to figure out whether I can install node in my system without downloading the Msi or tar.gz file. and somehow achieve a one-click installation for node.

Comment: Ok so you can find portable node project here : https://github.com/crazy-max/nodejs-portable